# Can't Download Apps From Store

Tags: 8.1, store, lumia-520

Why can't I install any apps on my phone? It says to try later. I tried later several times, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How long have you left between retires? Have you tried connecting via WiFi?

Answer (score 2):

try to go to setting's and check if there is an error with the Microsoft account that you signed in to the phone, usually you should see errors like attention required or not up to date

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset your phone it via [Windows Device Recovery Tools](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq). Don't forget to backup all of your data first.

Comment: That is a bit extreme, especially if the issue was actually at the store end (and as [other people seem to be affected](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/11667/106) that may be the case)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Manually sync your Microsoft account.
2. Check whether there is enough storage in phone memory
3. Try downloading via WiFi.
4. Check your region, date and time.